# How can I use the \t [tab] operator to format a NSString in columns?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, text, nsstring, text-formatting

I would like to find a way to format a NSString like this:

```
Name:               John
Location:           Unknown
Type:               Unknown
Status:             Unknown
```

Right now I'm using this code to do it but the result is quite different:

The code:

```
serializedValue = [serializedValue stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@:\t\t%@\n",title, value];
```

Where `title` is the left column and `value` is the second one.

The result:

```
Name:       John
Location:       Unknown
Type:       Unknown
Status:     Unknown
```

Now, as you can see, adding always a constant number of tabs (\t), 2 in my case, doesn't do the trick, because some  words in the left column are longer and some are shorter. I'm wondering if there is a simple way to do this that I'm not aware of.

Comment: do want to print the string in the console ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NSString *titleColumn = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:", title] stringByPaddingToLength:20 withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0];
serializedValue = [serializedValue stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@", titleColumn, value];
```

Btw, it would be more efficient to use an `NSMutableString` for `serializedValue`.

Comment: Just needs `stringByAppendingFormat` changed to `stringByAppendingString` :)

Comment: stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@", titleColumn, value]

Comment: What about for non-monospaced font?