# iOS: Column formatting for NSString not working in UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, multiple-columns

I'm working on an iPad app and I need to be able to format some output on the screen in a columnar format. This was similar to my question:

[How can I use the \t [tab] operator to format a NSString in columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699930/how-can-i-use-the-t-tab-operator-to-format-a-nsstring-in-columns)

and I used that solution, unfortunately I'm not seeing the same results. My code is as follows:

```
    NSString* titleColumn = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", displayName] stringByPaddingToLength:25 withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0];
    NSString* serializedValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSString* valueAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.03f", value];
    serializedValue = [serializedValue stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@", titleColumn, valueAsString];
```

When logging the items in the console, they are properly aligned, however, when plugging them into a UITextView, they are misaligned. This is how I'm sticking them in the text view:

```
    NSMutableString* displayString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    for (NSString* entry in textToDisplay)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", entry);
        [displayString appendString:entry];
        [displayString appendString:@"\n"];
    }

    [self.fTextPanel setText:displayString];
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

In the log, it looks like this:

```
    Inclination              0.000  
    Version                  0.000  
    Inferior/Superior        0.000  
    Anterior/Posterior       0.500
```

And the UITextView version looks like this: [http://imgur.com/vrUzybP,OYxGVd8](https://imgur.com/vrUzybP,OYxGVd8)

Comment: can you post a screenshot of how they look in console vs. how they look in the textview?

Comment: done, question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for misaligned is the different width for each character. The best way for displaying this type of information is by using `UITableView`, You can use `title` and `subTitle` field for displaying or you can design a custom `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is because when drawing charachters (glymphs), each character will have different widths,i.e character small c and big C will take different widths for drawing , so it wont work. Even though there are two strings with equal lengths but different characters, the drawing text will have different widths.

What i would suggest you for this is to have **two textViews side by side**, render titles in one textVIew and values in the next TextView.

If the number of titles is large and if you enable scrolling in textVIews, **use delegate Methods of UIScrollView**, and when scrollHappens in either of them, set the contentOffset of the other to make it look like single TextView.

Hope this helps.